# Obtain a different result when evaluating Stanford NLP sentiment

Tags: stanford-nlp, sentiment-analysis

I downloaded Stanford NLP 3.5.2 and run sentiment analysis with default configuration (i.e. I did not change anything, just unzip and run).

```
java -cp "*" edu.stanford.nlp.sentiment.Evaluate -model edu/stanford/nlp/models/sentiment/sentiment.ser.gz -treebank test.txt

EVALUATION SUMMARY
Tested 82600 labels
  66258 correct
  16342 incorrect
  0.802155 accuracy
Tested 2210 roots
  976 correct
  1234 incorrect
  0.441629 accuracy
Label confusion matrix
      Guess/Gold       0       1       2       3       4    Marg. (Guess)
               0     323     161      27       3       3     517
               1    1294    5498    2245     652     148    9837
               2     292    2993   51972    2868     282   58407
               3      99     602    2283    7247    2140   12371
               4       0       1      21     228    1218    1468
    Marg. (Gold)    2008    9255   56548   10998    3791

               0        prec=0.62476, recall=0.16086, spec=0.99759, f1=0.25584
               1        prec=0.55891, recall=0.59406, spec=0.94084, f1=0.57595
               2        prec=0.88982, recall=0.91908, spec=0.75299, f1=0.90421
               3        prec=0.58581, recall=0.65894, spec=0.92844, f1=0.62022
               4        prec=0.8297, recall=0.32129, spec=0.99683, f1=0.46321

Root label confusion matrix
      Guess/Gold       0       1       2       3       4    Marg. (Guess)
               0      44      39       9       0       0      92
               1     193     451     190     131      36    1001
               2      23      62      82      30       8     205
               3      19      81     101     299     255     755
               4       0       0       7      50     100     157
    Marg. (Gold)     279     633     389     510     399

               0        prec=0.47826, recall=0.15771, spec=0.97514, f1=0.2372
               1        prec=0.45055, recall=0.71248, spec=0.65124, f1=0.55202
               2        prec=0.4, recall=0.2108, spec=0.93245, f1=0.27609
               3        prec=0.39603, recall=0.58627, spec=0.73176, f1=0.47273
               4        prec=0.63694, recall=0.25063, spec=0.96853, f1=0.35971

Approximate Negative label accuracy: 0.646009
Approximate Positive label accuracy: 0.732504
Combined approximate label accuracy: 0.695110
Approximate Negative root label accuracy: 0.797149
Approximate Positive root label accuracy: 0.774477
Combined approximate root label accuracy: 0.785832
```

The test.txt file is downloaded from http://nlp.stanford.edu/sentiment/trainDevTestTrees_PTB.zip (contains train.txt, dev.txt and test.txt). The download link is get from http://nlp.stanford.edu/sentiment/code.html

However, in the paper "Socher, R., Perelygin, A., Wu, J.Y., Chuang, J., Manning, C.D., Ng, A.Y. and Potts, C., 2013, October. Recursive deep models for semantic compositionality over a sentiment treebank. In Proceedings of the conference on empirical methods in natural language processing (EMNLP) (Vol. 1631, p. 1642)." which sentiment analysis tool is based on, the authors reported that the accuracy when classify 5 classes is **0.807**.

Is my results I obtained normal?

Answer (score 0):

I get the same results when I run it out of the box.  It would not surprise me if the version of their system they made for Stanford CoreNLP differs slightly from the version in the paper.